# problem while importing pandas, python 2.7, pip 19.1.1

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, installation

I'm using python 2.7 on a Mac and cannot install pandas. If I activate the Conda base environment then pandas works fine but not otherwise.

I've tried:

```
pip install pandas  
pip2 install pandas  
sudo pip install pandas  
pip easy_install pandas
```

The exact error when I try `pip install pandas` is as printed below:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/parser.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/parser.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/relativedelta.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/relativedelta.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/**init**.py', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/zoneinfo/**init**.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/zoneinfo/**init**.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/**init**.pyc', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/zoneinfo/**init**.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/zoneinfo/**init**.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/zoneinfo', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/zoneinfo'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/tz.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/tz.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/relativedelta.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/relativedelta.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/rrule.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/rrule.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/**init**.py', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/**init**.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/**init**.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/parser.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/parser.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/tzwin.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/tzwin.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/rrule.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/rrule.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/**init**.pyc', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/**init**.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/**init**.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/easter.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/easter.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/easter.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/easter.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/tz.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/tz.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/tzwin.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt/tzwin.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil', '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/ll/2w2bypwj1r72871bd71cj3300000gn/T/pip-uninstall-EPDiEt'")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `pip install pandas --user`

This way, you'll install it in a user directory, where you'll have all required permissions.